# Using lodash to group filter data and combine

Tags: lodash

I have output like so:

```
{ diagnosis: 'Flu' }
{ diagnosis: 'Down Syndrome' }
{ diagnosis: 'Down Syndrome' }
{ diagnosis: 'Epilepsy' }
{ diagnosis: 'Epilepsy' }
{ diagnosis: 'Muscle Spasm' }
{ diagnosis: 'Muscle Spasm' }
{ diagnosis: 'Epilepsy' }
{ diagnosis: 'Muscle Spasm' }
{ diagnosis: 'Nervousness' }
{ diagnosis: 'Weezing' }
{ diagnosis: 'Unknown' }
```

You'll notice that `Epilepsy` shows up 4 times, `Muscle Tension and Spasm` shows up 3 times and `Crazy Guy Syndrome` shows up 2 while the rest show up only once. I want to create an array with 3 most common illnesses, for example: `['Epilepsy', 'Muscle Tension and Spasm', 'Crazy Guy Syndrome']` and ignore the rest. I am trying to do this with lodash. Any suggestions? Currently I am using `_.groupBy()` with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that chains together several lodash functions:

```
_(data)
  .map('diagnosis')
  .countBy()
  .toPairs()
  .sortBy(_.last)
  .reverse()
  .take(3)
  .map(_.head)
  .value();
```

Here's what's going on:

1. `map('diagnosis')` creates a new array, with just the `diagnosis` property values
2. [countBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy) creates an object where the keys are the unique values of the array, and the values are the number of occurrences of that value
3. [toPairs()](https://lodash.com/docs#toPairs) converts the object to an array of key/value arrays
4. `sortBy(_.last)` uses [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) and [last()](https://lodash.com/docs#last) to sort the array based on how many times it occurs in the original `data`
5. `reverse()` is used to sort the array in descending order
6. `take(3)` uses [take()](https://lodash.com/docs#take) to limit the array result to the top three items
7. `map(_.head)` uses [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) and [head()](https://lodash.com/docs#head) to remove the sorting data

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution as well:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tt0ap67y/)**

```
_(data)
    .countBy('diagnosis') // counts by diagnosis key
    .invert() // inverts count value and diagnosis key for sorting 
    .map() // get all diagnosis values
    .reverse() // reverse
    .take(3) // take the top 3
    .value();
```